# Which Graph API will help me to fetch site usage details such as Unique viewers, Site visits, etc for an individual site?

Tags: spfx, microsoft-graph

My requirement is to create a small spfx webpart showing selected Sharepoint site's usage details.

I tried searching for this question, but landed up finding Graph api fetching usage details of Sharepoint as a whole. But my requirement is to fetch the count of site visits, unique viewers for individual site.
Pls help me with the web service/ graph api.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Ruchira you can get Site usage details with following call

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

I have described it in detail in my blog, where you can do it step by step:

https://sposcripts.com/access-sharepoint-via-graph-api-in-powershell/